# Question about why dependent variables and power with regressions?

Tags: regression, inference, econometrics, statistical-power, rare-events

Say I am estimating $y_i = \beta x_i + \eta_i$, and Y is either a rare outcome (random example: say deaths of mothers during pregnancy in a developed economy), or if y is an aggregate outcome made from a small group of observations (as (very) bad example off the top of my head, say the share of asian americans working in mining in the US by county or state- which I would think is likely small).

In multiple similar outcomes like these, I often hear 'you wont have enough power/I worry about having power to identify effects'.

Why exactly do these types of dependent variables lend themselves to power issues?

Comment: What they probably mean when they say that is that variance of the estimates of the coefficients will be too high because the sample size will be too low. The use of the term "power" is confusing but what they probably mean is that the variance is so high that the null hypothesis that the coefficient is zero won't be rejected because of the variance being too high.

Comment: That's probably why we usually say *statistical power* rather than power. This is common issue in the study of rare or orphan disease, adverse events, and the like. E.g., to [detect a small difference](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2020/02/03/what-sample-size-do-you-need-for-a-binomial-test-of-proportions.html) between two proportions using a $\chi^2$ test, you would need a very large sample size ($n=1000$ amounts to a statistical power of 0.25 to detect a difference of 0.02).

Comment: so just to clarify on this point in a regression based context, for an  outcome, like rare disease,, any 'treatment' would likely make a small difference (like lowering it from .01 to .096 or something similar?), so it will just be vary hard to discern if this difference is statistically signficant?

Comment: @Steve I assume you're familiar with type I error ($\alpha$), i.e. the risk of erroneously rejecting the null when it holds in reality. Now sometimes it happens we can't reject the null despite an apparently large effect (or an effect which makes sense from pragmatic considerations): this is where we talk about "lack of power", as there's still a chance that the alternative hypothesis holds but we haven't used enough subjects. This is why preliminary power analysis is helpful in determining the optimal number of subjects needed in a study in order to demonstrate an effect (of a given size).